# Should we kill the old "DoF with a kit lens" question due to its accepted wrong answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

The accepted answer to [How can I get dramatic shallow DOF with a kit lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5493/how-can-i-get-dramatic-shallow-dof-with-a-kit-lens) is factually incorrect (before I edited it). That's reflected in the consensus votes and in the other answers. Yet, there it sticks at the top of a very common question often linked to. Both the questioner and provider of the mistaken answer are no longer active on the site.

I edited the accepted answer, but I'm not super-happy with that as a solution. Another option would be to *replace* it with a new question asking basically the same thing, like [Should I use my kit lens at max aperture or max zoom for shallow depth of field?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/89294/should-i-use-my-kit-lens-at-max-aperture-or-max-zoom-for-shallow-depth-of-field). (That seems narrower, but it really isn't, when combined with [How can I maximize the "blurry background, sharp subject" (bokeh) effect?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-can-i-maximize-the-blurry-background-sharp-subject-bokeh-effect) as linked in the first question.)

Comment: @scottbb Thanks. Some nice irony in my error here. Everyone makes mistakes. :)

Comment: Don't know what your talking about. I never make misteaks. =)

Answer (score 7):

I think the thing to do is downvote the accepted answer. I wouldn't kill the question.

Comment: Too bad it can't be unstuck from the top.

Answer (score 4):

I get your frustration, but due to the large amount of good answers and analysis at the question, I think it should stay as **the** "++DoF with kit lens" question.

There are lots of examples of questions with poor accepted answers and other rocking answers on other Stack Exchanges. It's just a fact of life, I suppose... ?

Answer (score 1):

Your suggested "replacement question" is the one that I was pondering about when shooting with a kit lens, and not really knowing much about system cameras. I knew enough of the mechanics of DoF and bokeh, but got lost when trying to find any "sweet spot" in real use of the kit-lens and crop body. Then again, I was no "newcomer" to photography when I came to face this problem. The value of the original question, and those answers to it, is in the finding of the basics of photographic techniques on the beginner level. I'd let it be as it is.